# $/jQuery not defined when dynamically adding scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically adding `<script>` tags for different `.js` resources into the head, however I receive an error exclaiming that `jQuery is not defined`.

I know that jQuery is in fact working, as other functions further down the flow are working correctly. Below is the code that I am using to dynamically add these scripts to the header. As you can see, I also include jQuery before any other plugins.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", AddExternals)

function AddExternals(){
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";


    var t2e = document.createElement("script");
    t2e.type = "text/javascript";
    t2e.src = "/test/rfsystem/rfJavascript/table2excel.js";

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t2e);

   console.log(jQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just after appending the `script` tag you can not expect that the `script` has been pulled over from the network and is embedded on to your page. It will load asynchronously.

You need to wait, or you can use `.onload` on that `script`.

**Ex:**
You should also append the script to the DOM before attaching the onload event and You should set the src attribute after the onload event:

```
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
    jq.onload = function() { console.log(jQuery); };
    jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";
```

Comment: Ya because once document is parsed, appending script would load it asynchronously

Comment: It certainly won't have even started the executing the jQuery code until the function that added it to the DOM has finished running. JavaScript is single threaded.

Comment: @Quentin What do you mean? I'm not sure to understand it.

Comment: @A.Wolff previously i type `onLoad` which should be `onload`. Quentin was pointing this.

Comment: @void Ya but i'm talking about his first comment here